# Oracle pushing me ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Tags: oracle

```
create table accountDetails(
    accountNumber int unique,
    customerId int unique,
    balance int not null,
    password varchar(255) not null,
    type varchar(255) not null check(type in ('Savings','Current')),
    primary key(accountNumber,customerId) )


create table statusDetails(
    customerId int references accountDetails(customerId),  
    primarykey(customerId))
```

The last table resulted in an error

Comment: Try replacing `INT` with `NUMBER` or `INTEGER`. That's a first and secondly and mainly: replace `primarykey` with `primary key` :-)

Comment: You probably want `VARCHAR2` and not `VARCHAR` and why does `type` have a length of 255 when the constraint restricts it to have exactly 7 characters in either case? Also - please do not store passwords in plain text; use a one-way hashing function (with salt) and store that.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. Really gave me hope!!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your second table declaration is all wrong.  Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE statusdetails (
    customerid   INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_cust FOREIGN KEY ( customerid )
        REFERENCES accountdetails ( customerid )
)
```

Note: using "int" data type maps to a NUMBER(38), which may not be what you want.  Use the proper oracle data type names.

Comment: It's not *"all wrong"*. There's a single typo, and once we correct that Oracle will quite happily create the table.

Comment: Actually I noticed the mistake after posting. Instead of using "primary key" , I used  "primarykey" as combined. Anuways I appreciate all your help. Hoping forward to some more errors and learn from this community

Answer (score 0):

> The last table resulted in an error

`ORA-00902: invalid datatype` error happens when we try to define a column using an invalid datatype. It's logical really.

Now, you think you haven't declared a column with an invalid datatype, because you think `statusdetails` table has only one column, `customerid`. But if you look at your actual statement you follow that column with this:

```
primarykey(customerId))
```

Because you mis-typed `primary key` Oracle treats that line as an attempt to create a second column. Hence the error, because `(customerId)` *is* an invalid datatype. So all you need do is pop in the missing space and Oracle will create the table for you.

```
create table statusDetails(
    customerId int references accountDetails(customerId),  
    primary key(customerId))
```

---

You had a compilation error caused by a simple typo. A key skill for a developer is the ability to turn a cool eye on our own code. I urge you to work on acquiring that skill as soon as you can.

Comment: ..and at the same time Oracle should also work on slightly misleading error messages .:)

Comment: @KaushikNayak - Those error messages have been confusing journeyman programmers for more than twenty-five years (yep, the voice of experience) so I doubt Oracle will re-write them anytime soon :-)